# Possible to send variables to the index page in CherryPy?

Tags: python, cherrypy

For instance I want to visit http://localhost:8080/?var=val or similar with POST, but I get a 500 server error:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 606, in respond
>    cherrypy.response.body = self.handler()
>  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpdispatch.py", line 25, in __call__
>    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
> TypeError: index() takes no arguments (1 given)
> ```
>
> Powered by CherryPy 3.1.2

Comment: So how did you code your `index` function?  The error message says you didn't allow it to take any arguments, but it received one (`index` is presumably the function serving the "root" URL, by analogy to the `index.html` file that's generally fetched to serve "root" for static queries).

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong, was a logic error that I attributed wrongly to my own misunderstanding of the cherrypy library.

Comment: @tehryan Hey you are welcome and encouraged to share how you solved the issue in an Answer - then other people who have the same problem can see how to solve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible.

Here is an example (adapted from [the CherryPy tutorial](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/CherryPyTutorial)):

```
<form action="indexPostHandler" method="post">
    <p>Enter a value:</p>
    <input type="text" name="val" value=""/>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Login"/></p>
</form>
```

And, in your index, you can use something like the following to process the request:

```
class Root:
    # create form here
    def indexPostHandler(self, val=None):
        # do something with val here
        ...
```